# Unable to access sharepoint site in same domain but from different machine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, public-website

I have created new share point site on my production machine. But I am unable to access it from another machines which are on same domain.

My Site url:

```
http://sharepointsite0/
```

My server name:

```
sharepointsite01
```

The site which I created skipped'1' from url. Does it causing this issue?

Please suggest something on it.

Comment: Did you add the DNS alias?

Comment: Thanks for reply, could please guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed causing the issue.

Either add DNS record on your DNS server pointing *sharepointsite0* to the IP of the address, OR modify Alternate Access Mappings (AAM) of the site and change it from *sharepointsite0* to *sharepointsite01*, or alternatively add it to AAM beside the existing *sharepointsite0*.

Comment: Right, if you want to try before adding a DNS record, edit the file `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on the client machine